# Xcode issue with cin (can will be automatically given a zero and not allowed user input in Xcode7.3)

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc, cin

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
// insert code here...
int a;
std::cout << "please input"<<std::endl;
std::cin >> a;//it doesn't work
std::cout << a<<std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

Not allowed user to input

It just output

> please input 0 Program ended with exit code: 0

I have to add cin.ignore() and cin.clear() and cin.sync()

Whats wrong with my Xcode?

it seems like istream assignment zero to cin without user input

maybe it just Xcode bug
Thanks!

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not an acceptable problem description.

Comment: OP could not be bothered to indent it.  Closing as unclear.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i don't know how to describe it but it just doesn't work i think there are something in istream

Comment: Then I don't know how to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i think i find the solution

type in Terminal.app:
`defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode`

and now ay Xcode work perfectly

maybe it just my setting problem